# How to add another text decoration definition with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to add another text decoration class with the help of JavaScript to the link which already has a class associated to it.

I want something like the `<a>` activated link should have the `text:decoration=none` but i am not able to do it with CSS because it gets applied to all the links, then if I declare a new class of no decoration.

How is this possible with JavaScript?

Comment: wath do you mean exactly for "a activated"?

Comment: activated means the link i am actually present.. clicked and reached on the page..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('ELEMENT_ID_HERE');
elem.style.textDecoration = 'none';
```

Comment: my element has a class and not the id

Comment: @Rich B:  I don't think you need to go around editing other people's answers just to replace and ellipsis with a colon.  Seriously.

Answer (score 1):

If you set an unique ID to all the links you use and then refer to the link in your script you can change whatever links you want to change by:

```
document.getElementById('YourLinksId').style.textDecoration = 'overline';
document.getElementById('yourLinksId').onmouseover.style.textDecoration = 'blink';
```

The style you set directly on the element will overrid any attributes set in the css class.

Edit: Sorry I think I misunderstood your question. If you mean activated as when the link has been clicked, mouseover ect you can do the following:

```
a:link {color: #FF0000}     /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color: #00FF00}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color: #FF00FF}   /* mouse over link */
a:active {color: #0000FF}   /* selected link */
```

More resources at [w3schools](http://w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Comment: the a:active just serves the purpose of mouseover but say if i have clicked the link and is on the other age.. at that time i want my link to be with no decoration..

Comment: You do this by setting: a:visited {text-decoration: none} in your CSS. Is this how you thought of it?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CSS classes:

```
var element = document.getElementById(idOfElement);
element.className = element.className + " noDecorationClass";
```

This adds a new class to the element, you may also overwrite the existing one.

```
element.className = "noDecorationClass";
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a framework like mootools (http://mootools.net/).

With the framework its as simple as:

```
element.addClass('my_new_css_class');
```

or you could just add a new style

```
element.setStyle('text-decoration', 'none');
```

Answer (score 0):

An active link is **only active while it is being clicked on**.

As soon as you release the mouse button, it no longer has an *active* state. Therefore you can use a *a:active* that applies to *all* links as only one will ever be active at a time.

I'm guessing that you really want it to retain your text-decoration: none until another link is clicked in which case you will need JavaScript. If I'm wrong, just follow @ChrisAD's example, but add:

```
a:active {color: #0000FF;

   text-decoration: none;

}   /* selected link */
```